# Mustache + Spring boot + REST API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, mustache

I decided to make a project using Mustache + Spring Boot + REST API. Earlier, I used to write projects with the front-end used Java EE + Servlets + JSP. Now I decided to try to switch to Spring and write an application with a front-end. And I found a way to create a page on the front-end using Mustache, but if you use Mustache, then everything needs to be saved to the `model`, and I want to use REST API. I mean if it is possible? If it's possible I'll be happy if you show a piece of code your `RestController` and Mustache.
The question is 'if possible call endpoint from mustache?'.

Comment: You need to read [tour] and ask a focused question. This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Yeah! I see) I want to ask if is it possible? I`ve changed question.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create REST API using OpenAPI(https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/tutorials/openapi-3-tutorial.html) which uses the mustache file to create your code.

You need to add following dependencies,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

add the following plugin in the pom.xml for configuration(https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md),

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/templates
                </templateDirectory>
                <configOptions>
                    //add the configuration options here
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By default it uses the mustache files internally to generate codes, you can change the mustache files from the git location(https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/)/create your own with the name mentioned in git and place it in the location ${project.basedir}/templates it will generate your codes during the compile time and you can use them in your project.

Place the OpenAPI document in the resource folder where application.properties is placed

Comment: So, I guess writing java code in mustache is a bad idea

Comment: @Jeka_FRI it is not bad idea it is based on your need. Instead of going with the documentation after you developed your API it gives the advantage of giving the UI developers/API consumers how your API input and output and the structure everything using an auto enabled endpoint in your application. Also it is called design first approach instead of code first approach. As I said it is all about your application design decision whether to use it or not.

Comment: what about incapsulation?

Comment: @Jeka_FRI I don't get what you want exactly. Can you elaborate what you are trying to ask? So, I can help you with more information.